# How to send back to custom class which object of that class was clicked

Tags: haxe, openfl

I am stack at this problem can't figure out how to do it properly. [Haxe/OpenFL]

I want to make following menu. On screen for player display three images/buttons. When player clicks on one of the images/buttons a text with description appears under that button.

My is, i dont know how to send from Main (where i create this buttons and using them), send info to custom class of this images/buttons, what specific button/image was pressed.

Here is example code, first from custom class of the images/buttons:

```
class CusstomButtons extends Sprite {

var buttonImagePath:String;
var _buttonImagePath:String;

var buttonName:String;
var _buttonName:String;

var button1Btmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap ();
var button1Sprt:Sprite = new Sprite();

var button2Btmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap ();
var button2Sprt:Sprite = new Sprite();

var buttonText1:TextField = new TextField ();
var buttonText2:TextField = new TextField ();

public function new(buttonImagePath, buttonName) {

    super();

    _buttonImagePath = buttonImagePath;
    _buttonName = buttonName;

    createButton ();
}

public function createButton () :Void {

if (_buttonName == Button1){
button1Btmp = new Bitmap (Assets.getBitmapData (_buttonImagePath));
button1Sprt.addChild(button1Btmp);
addChild(button1Sprt);
//Here goes the code for button position and tweening
}

if (_buttonName == Button2){
button2Btmp = new Bitmap (Assets.getBitmapData (_buttonImagePath));
button2Sprt.addChild(button2Btmp);
addChild(button2Sprt);
//Here goes the code for button position and tweening
}
}

public function displayButtonDescrition () :Void {

    if (button1) {
        buttonText1.text = "Some text for Button 1"
        addChild(buttonText1);
        //Here goes code for button position and etc
    }
    if (button2) {
        buttonText2.text = "Some text for Button 2"
        addChild(buttonText2);
        //Here goes code for button position and etc
    }
}
}
```

And here is code from main:

```
class Main extends Sprite {
public var button1Menu:CusstomButtons;
public var button2Menu:CusstomButtons;

public function new () {

    super ();
    button1Menu = new CusstomButtons ("path/button1", "button1");
    button1Menu = new CusstomButtons ("path/button1", "button2");
}

public function createButtonMenu ():Void {

button1Menu.createButton();
addChild(button1Menu);
button2Menu.createButton();
addChild(button2Menu);

button1Menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
button2Menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
}

public function onClick (event:MouseEvent):Void {

if (event.currentTarget == button1Menu) {
    button1Menu.displayButtonDescrition();
    }
if (event.currentTarget == button2Menu) {
    button2Menu.displayButtonDescrition();
    }
}
}
```

The main question is how to use one function to display different description texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a static field in the Button class to hold all created instances of it.

```
static var instances = new Array();
```

Then in the Button constructor store the instance that is currently being created

```
instances.push(this);
```

Finally, from the main class call a static method in the button class, passing the clicked instance:

```
public static function setClickedInstance(instance:Button):Void{
   //manipulation code goes here
}
```

And in the main class call the method when necessary:

```
Button.setClickedInstance();
```

Sorry if above doesn't compile as I couldn't test it right now. If not, it probably just needs a bit of tweaking.

An alternative would be to add a mouse listener in the Button class itself, but then you wouldn't have control in the main class when to "react" on clicks and when not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry for my dumbness :) But i am still learning. Can you be more specific. First two lines i understand how they work and where to put them. But where i put the setClickedInstance function instance? If you can, can you please use my example to show how its done.

Comment: You put it in the Button class (CusstomButtons in your case)

Then call it from the main class by referencing it through the class name like this: CusstomButtons.setClickedInstance(event.currentTarget) inside the click listener.

Comment: Thank you for the response and solution, great help. :)